# imagePullSecrets has no effect and authentication still required

Tags: kubernetes, cri-o, docker-registry-mirror

I have a k8s cluster v1.26.4 and all the nodes have crio v1.25.2 installed.

I have private registry with basic auth that mimics as another private registry to reduce code writing. The registry is a [docker distribution](https://distribution.github.io/distribution/) solution with proxy-mode for latter. Then i have **mirror.conf** for cri-o as is:

```
[[registry]]
prefix = private.registry
location = mirror.registry
```

When i execute
`crictl pull --creds private.registry/image:tag`
everything is ok. But when i create a pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: pod
  name: pod
  namespace: my-ns
spec:
  containers:
    - image: private.registry/image:tag
      name: pod
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: registry-secret
```

and a secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: base64-encoded-auths
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: registry-secret
  namespace: my-ns
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

then i have this error:
`Failed to pull image "private.registry/image:tag": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = reading manifest tag in mirror.registry/image: unauthorized: authentication required`

If i rewrite the **mirror.conf** for cri-o when prefix and location are the same then no issues whatsoever. This means that my auths in a secret are most likely correct.

```
[[registry]]
prefix = mirror.registry
location = mirror.registry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out direct requests through `crictl pull` were not working as well, so the cri-o could be the isse.

After researching in i've found couple of similar questions ([this](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o/issues/4941) and [this](https://github.com/Trow-Registry/trow/issues/251)) about missing credentials when using redirect(*prefix*)/mirror with cri-o. The reason is credentials are stripped when named endpoint and the actual are not the same. It is done intentionally to avoid credentials leaking and [commented right in a library project](https://github.com/containers/image/blob/97b3ffa7bb92a7778238b58010454031b0c2cbee/docker/docker_image_src.go#L111). Looks like there is only one solution to use **global_auth_file** option in **crio.conf** file, which works.